# Big title overlaps with axis' number

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Code:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
  \begin{axis}[
    title=Oxford CROW features Parallel Search,
    xlabel=$Threads$,
    ylabel=$Time$ (sec),
    legend pos=north east]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1, 3.18099e-05)
    (2, 3.02396e-05)
    (4, 1.05439e-05)
    };
    \addplot [red,mark=triangle] coordinates {
        (1, 0.000515463)
    (2, 0.000272568)
    (4, 0.000166557)
    };
     \addplot [green,mark=square] coordinates {
        (1, 0.000517588)
    (2, 0.000410064)
    (4, 0.000166227)
    };
  \addlegendentry{$threshold = N * 1\%$}
  \addlegendentry{$threshold = N * 5\%$}
  \addlegendentry{$threshold = N * 10\%$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Oxford CROW features, $N$ = 5063, $D$ = 512, Parallel Search.}
\label{crowParSearch}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output (notice how the title overlaps with that number):

[image]

Any idea on how to make this overlap disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `width` option to make the plot wider. This also gives more space for the legend such it doesn't overlap with the plot.
- Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` (or whichever version you use, see the note in the log file) such the label of the y-axis moves closer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    title=Oxford CROW features Parallel Search,
    xlabel=$Threads$,
    ylabel=$Time$ (sec),
    legend pos=north east]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1, 3.18099e-05)
    (2, 3.02396e-05)
    (4, 1.05439e-05)
    };
    \addplot [red,mark=triangle] coordinates {
        (1, 0.000515463)
    (2, 0.000272568)
    (4, 0.000166557)
    };
     \addplot [green,mark=square] coordinates {
        (1, 0.000517588)
    (2, 0.000410064)
    (4, 0.000166227)
    };
  \addlegendentry{$threshold = N * 1\%$}
  \addlegendentry{$threshold = N * 5\%$}
  \addlegendentry{$threshold = N * 10\%$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Oxford CROW features, $N$ = 5063, $D$ = 512, Parallel Search.}
\label{crowParSearch}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```